# Why would Intellij 14 Ultimate with GWT 2.7 Super Dev Mode debugging stop working?

Tags: java, debugging, gwt, intellij-idea, gwt-super-dev-mode

I have my setup running GWT 2.7 Super Dev Mode, IntelliJ 14 Ultimate, and Google Chrome.

I had the debugging working in IntelliJ for a couple sesssions and then it stopped all of a sudden.  I can go back to "classic mode" by just switching the Super Dev Mode flag off, no code changes, and debugging works again.  Super Dev Mode in IntelliJ has never started to work again after the first time. I can also debug in Chrome with the sourcemaps when Super Dev Mode is on.

Has anyone else seen this yet, and have a work around or fix?

I have tried

- switching between dev mode types
- Invalidating caches and restarting
- reinstalling the JetBrains Chrome plugin

Comment: I have no problems using IntelliJ 14 and SDM. Did you delete the generated sources? Any informations in the log if you start SDm with logLevel TRACE?

Comment: I figured it out.  I must have lost the change that turns on the JavaScript debugger in the run configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JavasScript debugger checkbox was not checked in run configuration for the application in IntelliJ.